# Can't block bots in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, bots

I tried to block bad bots via htaccess with this code:
I know these are 2 ways to do so, but none of them is working, I still see the bots in the access-log: What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BLEXBot [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SemrushBot [NC,OR]
```

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "BLEXBot" rotbot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SemrushBot" rotbot

<Limit POST GET HEAD PUT>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from env=rotbot
</Limit>
```

The entries in the access log look like that:

```
domain.org:443 46.229.168.142 - - [22/Jul/2019:08:56:26 +0200] "GET /path/to/page/ HTTP/1.1" 403 3801 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/3~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)"
domain.org:443 94.130.219.232 - - [22/Jul/2019:08:56:24 +0200] "GET /path/to/page/ HTTP/1.1" 403 760 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; BLEXBot/1.0; +http://webmeup-crawler.com/)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix these rules to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BLEXBot [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SemrushBot [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```